# Identify caller id, hung up, call back with asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip

For a project I need to build an mvp of a service where users call a toll free number, on the other side, the pbx detects the call, saves the caller # and hangs up (so caller never gets charged for the call). Then the pbx calls the user back, allows him to dial a #, then pbx plays an audio file and when it finishes, makes the connection to the # introduced by the user.

I'm new to voip and asterisk, but which documentation should I read to achieve this (which features do I need to understand and look for?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At begining you have to understand how to build [dialplan](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+extensions.conf) and use it's applications([Dial](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial), [Playback](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Playback) and [Read](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Read)). If you want to use some programming language you can use [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI), there are library to write agi in almost all languages :)

For redialing user you can use [call files](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out) or [Asterisk Manager](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API) function [originate](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate). Call file can be used to call in future if you change creation time of file to future.

Simple flow can look like this:

1. User dial simple [dialplan](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+extensions.conf), run there some [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI), which read [callerid](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+callerid) and saves [call file](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out) in near future. You do this without answering the call.
2. [Call file](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out) dials user.
3. After answer you go to another dialplan which [reads](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Read) dtmf from user and [dial](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial) that number.

Comment: That's great @gkocjan do you think asterisk is the best option to do this? Also this could be possible to be run on a cloud server?

Comment: I didn't try, but Asterisk can run on almost all unix platforms. You can also check freeswitch software, but I only hear about this. If my answer was helpful you can mark it ;)